# How to test Rest API endpoint which takes value from constantly changing external API

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, testing, integration-testing

I use external API, which returns list of sorted by date `Objects` with many (approx. 30) properties.

I wrote simple Rest API using Spring Boot with one endpoint 
`/newest_obj_name`
which just return currently newest name of Object from that list and ignore everything else.

How can I sufficiently test that code while the value from external API is constantly changing, so I cannot simply use `String expected` as in a code below?

Generally speaking how to approach whole testing issue in that scenario?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MyTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();

    private HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    @Test
    public void testRetrieveNewest() {

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(null, headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                createURLWithPort("/newest_obj_name"),
                HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

        String expected = "{\"name\":\"crazy\"}";

        try {
            JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, response.getBody(), false);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String createURLWithPort(String uri) {
        return "http://localhost:" + port + uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Write a unit test which mocks the external API and tests that your logic is correct. In this integration test, just check that the response has the expected structure, but without testing the actual value.

Comment: Could you provide some snippet code? 
Because in order to extract that String name I needed to transform ResponseEntity inside my Service. So if I am not wrong when I'll write unit test I will be testing code from my Service using exactly the same code to transform response from external API on the fly?